# How to subclass UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to subclass UIImagePickerController. I want to add cameraOverlays to it. However, I want to do this with the aid of the story board. So I connected the UIImagePickerController to a UIViewController in Storyboard with a button for testing. Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class ImagePickerViewController: UIImagePickerController {

  @IBOulet weak var button: UIButton!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.cameraOverlayView?.addSubview(button)
  }

}
```

With this code however, I get an error saying `found nil while executing the code`. I hope my question makes sense. Basically I want to add camera overlays without programmatically writing all of it. I want to design the overlays in the storyboard and just somehow call them and add them to my camera overlays. How can I make this work?

Comment: did you connect the `button` in the interface builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a view with your custom controls, and assign that to the property cameraOverlayView, the cameraOverlayView is nil by default, you have to set it to some view.

You should not subclass UIImagePickerController, instead, create a custom view for the overlay, and the object that instantiates the pickerController should simply assign it to that property. That way, you do not have to subclass, as per the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/) (emphasis mine):

> IMPORTANT
>
> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. **This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.** The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.